# rails form_for does not submit to create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I'm trying to set up a new user registration form and for some reason when I submit the form it just flashes on the screen and the information does not hit the db. I'm almost positive it never makes it to the `create` action as I've placed a `binding.pry` on the first line of the `create` method and the server never pauses for it. It also updates the url to the following: `http://localhost:3000/register?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=z%2FZxe...`

I'm assuming I'm missing something basic, but haven't been able to figure it out after hours of research and refactoring. Here is my code:

model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password validations: false
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, on: :create, length: {minimum: 7}
end
```

controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully registered."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end
end
```

view:

```
<%= render 'shared/title', title: 'New User Registration:' %>

<div class='col-lg-6'>
  <div class='well bs-component'>
    <form class='form-horizontal'>
      <legend>Enter New User Details</legend>
      <hr/>
      <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error', obj: @user %>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <%= f.label :username, class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
          <div class='col-lg-10'>
            <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control empty', placeholder: 'Username' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <%= f.label :email, class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
          <div class='col-lg-10'>
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control empty', placeholder: 'Email' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <%= f.label :password, class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
          <div class='col-lg-10'>
            <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control empty', placeholder: 'Password' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit @user.new_record? ? "Register" : "Update Profile", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %> 
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes:

```
get '/register', to: 'users#new'
resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update]
```

I'm using rails v.4.2.4 and ruby v.2.1.6. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

UPDATE:

Here is the error partial rendered in the form per Michal's request:

```
<% if obj.errors.any? %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
      <h5>Oh Snap! The following errors occured:</h5>
      <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you paste code for rendered form?

Comment: I take it you are not using Devise for registration?

Comment: SunnyK - no, I'm just using the baked in functionality via bcrypt v.3.1.7 and `has_secure_password`

Comment: Have you got a `before_action` in the application controller that might be intercepting the create action?  If not, try creating a `before_action` that calls `binding.pry` and you can inspect the params to see what controller and method is being called.

Comment: One thing I noticed is the url/path that the form is trying to submit to => `/register`. On the other hand, your route specifies a `resource` for users, which means that the create action for your users controller should be available under `/users` with a post method. I think one thing you can do here is to exclusively provide the url to the `users#create` action in your `form_for @user, url: create_user_path`... this will ensure that the submit action on the form goes to the intended controller action....

Comment: Steve- I do have 2 `before_actions`:   `before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]` and `before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update]`. I tried creating a before action to inject a `binding.pry` but it still didn't register...

Comment: Try to remove html form tag ( <form class='form-horizontal'>) from your view

Comment: Guarav Gupta - You had it correct, once I changed the `form` tag to a `div` it worked as expected. Please submit as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guarav Gupta was correct in the comments. Once I changed the 'form' tag to a 'div' tag in the view it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a routing error.

change `get '/register', to: 'users#new'` to `get '/register, to: 'users#create''`

This will save the user to the db.